# sklearn rfecv inconsistent results for feature selection

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I was trying to to feature selection with RFECV:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_matrix,
                                                    y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

selector = RFECV(DecisionTreeRegressor(), min_features_to_select=5,
                  step=5, cv=2, n_jobs=-1)
selector.fit(X_train ,y_train)


print(selector.support_)
```

The printed output is a mask for feature selection, however every execution it returns a different mask.
The X and y dataframe are ok.

Outputs:

## 1

[ True  True  True  True  True False False False  True  True False  True
True  True  True  True False  True  True False  True  True  True  True
True  True  True  True  True  True False  True  True  True  True  True
True  True  True  True  True False False  True False  True  True]

## 2

[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]

## 3

[False  True False False  True False False False  True  True False False
False False False  True False  True False False False False False False
False False  True False False False False False False False False  True
True  True  True  True False False False False False False False]

and so on...

What might be the cause?

Comment: `DecisionTreeRegressor` also have a `random_state` param which should be set to get reproducible results. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39158831/3374996

Comment: @VivekKumar you are right, but I find it still weird as the number of features which is passed should not depend on the regressor?

Comment: @VivekKumar and @Mario L - How do we set `n_features` in RFECV? I don't wish to assign `min_no_of_features_to_select`. I would like to select `Top 15 features`. How can I do that?

Comment: @SSMK You set `step` as "total_features - 15" and leave `min_no_of_features_to_select` as default.

Comment: Can you help me with this if you have time?  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/64906/how-to-transform-specific-type-feature-to-yield-better-prediction