# machine learning model upon persisting performance reduces

Tags: python, machine-learning, mapr, pyspark

I have built a preliminary ML (`PySpark`) model with sample data on my PC (`Windows`) and the accuracy is around 70%. After persisting `model binary` on disk I am reading it from a different jupyter notebook and the accuracy is somewhere near 70%. Now if I do the same thing on our cluster (`MapR/Unix`), after reading the `model binary` from disk, accuracy goes down to 10-11% (the dataset is also exactly same). Even with the full dataset I got the same issue (just for information).

As the cluster has Unix OS, I tried training-persisting-testing the model in a docker container (Unix), but no issue there. The issue is only with the cluster.

I have been scratching my head since then about what might be causing this and how to resolve it. Please help.

**Edit:**

It's a classification problem and I have used `pyspark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier`.

To persist the models I am simply using the standard setup:

`model.write().overwrite().save(model_path)`

And to load the model:

`model = pyspark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel().load(model_path)`

I have used `StringIndexer`, `OneHotEncoder` etc in the model and have also persisted them on disk to in order to use them in the other jupyter notebook (same way as the main model).

**Edit:**

Python: 3.x
Spark: 2.3.1

Comment: Sounds very weird. Could we get some more information about the model?

Comment: Sure. I will edit my question to add more info. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: The serialization strategy that you used it to persist the model, kind of model, etc.

Comment: did you fix the random_state ? Here is an explanation why this can have an impact: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39158003/confused-about-random-state-in-decision-tree-of-scikit-learn

Comment: No I didn't. And I am using the same code (end to end) everywhere. So shouldn't matter even if I did.